# Use IO when creating Xmonad configuration (keymap depends on number of connected monitors)

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm trying to set up different Xmonad key mappings depending on the number of connected monitors. The reason is that I use the same Xmonad config file on multiple systems (desktops, a laptop with different monitor configurations including 3 displays). Displays are listed in a different order on different systems, that's why I need to hardcode display indices when using a 3 monitor setup.

My current best try is something like that (everything that is not relevant has been removed):

```
import qualified Graphics.X11.Xlib as X11
import qualified Graphics.X11.Xinerama as X11

screenKeysFor2Monitors conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $
  [((m .|. mod4Mask, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f)) -- Replace 'mod1Mask' with your mod key of choice.
      | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_w, xK_e] [0, 1] -- Usual screen order
      , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask), (W.greedyView, mod1Mask)]]

screenKeysFor3Monitors conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $
  [((m .|. mod4Mask, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f)) -- Replace 'mod1Mask' with your mod key of choice.
      | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_w, xK_e, xK_q] [0, 2, 1] -- hardcoded according to laptop driver
      , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask), (W.greedyView, mod1Mask)]]


screenKeys x = do
        numberOfScreens <- getScreens
        keyConfig <- case numberOfScreens of
                        3 -> screenKeysFor3Monitors x
                        _ -> screenKeysFor2Monitors x
        return keyConfig

-- | Get number of screens
getScreens = do
  screens <- do
    dpy <- X11.openDisplay ""
    rects <- X11.getScreenInfo dpy
    X11.closeDisplay dpy
    return rects
  pure $ length screens

xmonadConfig = ewmh xfceConfig{
          modMask = mod4Mask
          keys = MyKeys.screenKeys
}
```

I get this error

```
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/me/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

lib/MyXMonad/Keys.hs:51:64: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `M.Map (KeyMask, KeySym) (X ())`
                  with actual type `IO (X ())`
    * In the expression: (screenKeys x)
      In the second argument of `($)`, namely
        `[(myKeysToAdd x), (workspaceKeys x), (screenKeys x)]`
      In the expression:
        M.unions $ [(myKeysToAdd x), (workspaceKeys x), (screenKeys x)]
   |
51 | keysToAdd x = M.unions $ [(myKeysToAdd x), (workspaceKeys x), (screenKeys x)]
   |                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^

lib/MyXMonad/Keys.hs:242:30: error:
    * Couldn't match type `M.Map (KeyMask, KeySym)` with `IO`
      Expected type: IO (X ())
        Actual type: M.Map (KeyMask, KeySym) (X ())
    * In the expression: screenKeysFor3Monitors x
      In a case alternative: 3 -> screenKeysFor3Monitors x
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        keyConfig <- case numberOfScreens of
                       3 -> screenKeysFor3Monitors x
                       _ -> screenKeysFor2Monitors x
    |
242 |                         3 -> screenKeysFor3Monitors x
    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

lib/MyXMonad/Keys.hs:243:30: error:
    * Couldn't match type `M.Map (KeyMask, KeySym)` with `IO`
      Expected type: IO (X ())
        Actual type: M.Map (KeyMask, KeySym) (X ())
    * In the expression: screenKeysFor2Monitors x
      In a case alternative: _ -> screenKeysFor2Monitors x
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        keyConfig <- case numberOfScreens of
                       3 -> screenKeysFor3Monitors x
                       _ -> screenKeysFor2Monitors x
    |
243 |                         _ -> screenKeysFor2Monitors x
    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Please check the file for errors.
```

If I understand correctly, the problem here is that my code depends on side effects (working with monitor configuration uses IO monad) and becomes non-pure. I can convert `IO` monad to `X` monad using `liftIO`. But the `X` monad is accessible only inside key binding handlers. The code that creates key bindings for Xmonad configuration has to be pure, and `X` monad is not expected here.

In other words, if I get the situation right, it's not possible to define key bindings using non-pure functions (e.g. by looking on connected monitors). Maybe there is some workaround? I lack a decent understanding of Haskell and maybe I'm missing something obvious for regular Haskell programmers.

Comment: You write `keyConfig <- ...`. But the `...` is a pure thing (doesn't do any `IO`). Use `let keyConfig = ...` for pure things, `<-` for `IO`-y things. You might also like [The IO Monad for People who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html).

Comment: I see, will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, as an alternative you could use a conditional within the actual keybinding itself - with the advantage that it is run at the time it is invoked as opposed to xmonad startup.

Comment: yes, I was thinking about that as a workaround that would work anyway inside the monadic scope. But that was going to result in somewhat complicated code, and luckily lsmor has pointed me out to take a look on the `main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not too familiar with Xmonad but you can easily do the following I guess. create a pure function `mkConfig`  which takes the number of screens and returns the desired key mapping. Then, in your `main` pass it to `xmonad` function. I haven't tried to compile any of this but probably you can modify it easily

```hs
mkConfig numberOfScreens  = -- Notice that this is a pure function
 case numberOfScreens of
   3 -> screenKeysFor3Monitors x
   _ -> screenKeysFor2Monitors x


main :: IO ()
main = do
 numberOfScreens <- getScreens                                              -- Retrive the number of screens from the system
 let keyConfig = mkConfig numberOfScreens                                   -- Makes a key mapping out of this
     xmonadConfig = ewmh xfceConfig{ modMask = mod4Mask, keys = keyConfig } -- Creates a Xmonad configuration

 xmonad xmonadConfig  -- Launch Xmonad.
```

Comment: You are my saver! I'm trying to learn Haskell by trial (purely for Xmonad configuration purposes), and my experience with Java, Python, Scala, Bash, Typescript and React helps me a lot. So I had a slight feeling of what is happening, but totally missed out the `main`. Thanks a lot!